# Coding Style to init control on form

Tags: vba, coding-style

Is this the right way to fill the combobox?

On form combox are named as `cmbType1`,`cmbType2`,`cmbType3` ...  and so on.

I am using following kind of logic to initialise the combo box:

```
Private Sub fillCombo(count As Integer)
    Dim cmbControl As Object
    For i = 1 To count

        Set cmbControl = Me.Controls.item("cmbType" + CStr(i))
        cmbConnectorTypeControl.AddItem ("ABC")
    Next i
End Sub
```

So I just want cross verify this that is this the correct style of coding?

Any suggestions are most welcome...

Comment: VB6 allows for control arrays which negates the need for a lookup-by-name, VBA does not - which are you using? In either case there is stricter typing than `as object` available, and should `cmbConnectorTypeControl` not be `cmbControl`?

Comment: cmbConnectorTypeControl - just type mistake :)

Comment: VBA and my combo boxes are named like combo1 to combo10 and all of then needs to fill with the same value as "ABC"

Comment: Then this is an effective way of doing it (with Beaner's addition).  You could remove the need to specify the count in advance by looping all the controls & looking at their type & name.

Answer (score 2):

Alex is correct. If you have your combo boxes already on the form and your generic fillCombo method works then try changing the method to take a **ComboBox** as the parameter. It will save the hit for doing the look up and simplify the code. I assume you are not really adding "ABC" to all the comboboxs up to the count, but even if you are I would rather call this method in a loop.

```
Private Sub fillCombo(ByVal vCombobox As ComboBox)

    vCombobox.AddItem ("ABC")

End Sub
```

Comment: my combo boxes are named like combo1 to combo10 and all of then needs to fill with the same value as "ABC"

Comment: @Matt Either works although there may be fine points that argue in favor of using ByRef. For me, I don't want to accidently change the passed in control (pretty unlikely but ...) so I use ByVal. I can update and make changes to the control, but I can't actually change the control itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip needing to specify the initial count;

```
fillCombo "cmbType"
...
function fillCombo(name)
dim ctrl as Control
for each Control in Me.Controls
    if typeof Control is ComboBox then
        if left$(Control.name, len(name)) = name then
            Control.additem "ABC"
        end if
    end if
next
end function
```